# mod_rewrite for favicon control?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm making several subdomains as what will basically be portals to the same site on Namecheap. Redirecting subdomains is actually really easy (especially since the plumbing is hidden from me),but I want the favicons to be different. This is crucial because the site is crawled by robots that probably don't care about Javascript or the like.

How would I get a request for `http://newsubdomain.example.com/favicon.ico` to go to `http://oldsubdomain.example.com/differentfavicon.ico` instead?

Since I'm a huge n00b in mod_rewrite and most of .htaccess in general, I don't know if it's significant that I'm ultimately storing the files in a structure similar to 
`http://example.com/oldsubdomain/differentfavicon.ico` ...

I could probably use PHP if worse came to worst, but I'm trying to avoid adding yet another language to the list of things my little project requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I get a request for `http://newsubdomain.example.com/favicon.ico` to go to `http://oldsubdomain.example.com/differentfavicon.ico`

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =newsubdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(favicon\.ico)$ http://oldsubdomain.example.com/different$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```